# Android Matrix operation throws IllegalStateException

Tags: android, matrix, illegalstateexception

I defined a custom view extending class View.

```
public class MyView extends View{
   public MyView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs); 
       Matrix m= new Matrix();
       //this line is ok
       m.setScale(...);
   }   

   public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){
       //this same operation throws "IllegalStateException: Matrix can not be modified" 
       m.setScale(...);
   }
}
```

I am wondering why I am getting such an exception. I searched the web but found no clues at all.

Answer (score 0):

Declare the `Matrix` object `m` at class level as below...

```
public class MyView extends View{

   Matrix m;

   public MyView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
       super(context, attrs); 

       m = new Matrix();
       m.setScale(...);
   }   

   public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){

       m.setScale(...);

       return true;
   }
}
```

Comment: I've found why. It was my bad. I thought I initialized my matrix using m = new Matrix(); but actually "m = getMatrix()" in the code. Sorry about that. It seems like the matrix of the view is immutable. That's the reason I am getting an exception?